# Layout restriction on a non-standard layout class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the compiler free to reorder data in a non-standard layout class? For example, is it allowed to change

```
struct
{
    char x;
private:
    short y;
public:
    char z;
};
```

to

```
struct
{
private:
    short y;
public:
    char x;
    char z;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: I misremembered the quote originally, the compiler is allowed to do that per `9.2/14`:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with different access control is unspecified (11).
>   Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members
>   not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might
>   requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and
>   virtual base classes (10.1)

What it can't do is reorder attributes with the same access specifier.

That said I don't know of any implementation that takes the liberty to reorder attributes even across access specifiers.

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to change the order within each access specification.  The order of each access specification segnment is unspecified.  The compiler is allowed to do what the O.P. demonstrates.